# How can I find products with a given remainder efficiently in C++?

Tags: c++, modulo

If I am given a number like 23,128,765 and I am given two more numbers 9 and 3, I want to calculate the number of pairs such that for 9 and 3 the substrings whose remainder is 3 when divided by 9 are: 3, 31,287, 12, and 876.

How can I calculate the number of such substrings using C++?

One possible way is to calculate all possible substrings but that is O(n^2), but I want something faster than that.

Comment: Transform the string to a vector of int, one int for each digit. Then use the fact the remainder when dividing by 9 is the same as the remainder when dividing the sum of the digits by 9. It will still be O(n^2), but with a very small constant, just a few clock cycles, in front of the n^2.

Comment: But `9` and  `3` are just examples, these number can vary till 500.

Comment: You can still do it quite efficiently by working with a vector of integers, one for each digit. Just a few clock cycles more than in the n = 9 case.

Comment: The Time limit specified is 2 seconds. And maximum length of input is 10^4 which is not possible with O(n^2).

Comment: You can do it in time O(n) where n is the number of digits. The key is to look at the partial sums of the sequence 5, 60, 700, ... , 2000000 modulo the divisor.

Comment: This sounds like a contest or homework assignment. Make sure the contest rules/homework rules permit asking the internet for help.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for C++, but here's a solution in Common Lisp, which was easier to write and demonstrate in this context:

```
(defun quotients-with-remainder-in (n divisor remainder)
  (loop with str = (format nil "~D" n)
        for i upfrom remainder to n by divisor
        when (search (format nil "~D" i) str)
          collect i))

> (quotients-with-remainder-in 23128765 9 3)
(3 12 876 31287)
```

This strides upward by the divisor, and converts each potential product into a string a searches for that string within the upper bound number's string representation.

That creates many strings along the way, but finding a way to manipulate integers to see whether the decimal representation of one occurs within the decimal representation of another is not amenable to any arithmetic operations. For instance, figuring out whether the number 131 "contains" a 3 can't be accomplished with arithmetic and inspection of a two's complement representation.

Well, let's see; perhaps you could multiply the candidate number by factors of 10, and for each such product subtract it from the original number, and then check whether the important digits in the difference are all zero, for which you can use the modulus operator against a power of 10 one greater than the base-10 logarithm of the product. I started writing such a solution, an it quickly went off the rails. Using the extra logarithms, multiplication, and division will likely yield a solution even slower than the string conversion and substring searching.